# What are the uses of rel='noreferrer' in html links or download links? How is it useful?

Tags: html

What are the uses of `rel='noreferrer'` in general?

I want to add it to my download links and some external/internal links.

1. What are the cons/pros of hiding referal?
2. Does google/search engines find it sneaky?

Comment: Why do you want to add it if you do not know what its uses are and how it might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

```
rel=noreferrer
```

It indicates that no referrer information is to be leaked when following the link.

New in `HTML 5`

No browser currently supports this.

Comment: I thought chrome does? at least it worked on mine v40